# How to use Quaternion with lwjgl?

Tags: java, opengl, rotation, lwjgl, quaternions

I'm doing a 3D game with lwjgl. I want to be able to rotate object with the x y and z axis with quaternion (to avoid gimbal lock) but it doesn't work.

Here's my code :

```
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.util.vector.*;


public class Node{
    private double[] pos;
    private Quaternion rotation;
    public static float PI180 = (float)Math.PI/180;

public Node(){
    pos = new double[]{0,0,0};
    rotation = new Quaternion();
}

protected void apply(){
    GL11.glTranslated(pos[0],pos[1],pos[2]);
    float[] axis = getAxisAngle();
    GL11.glRotatef(axis[0], axis[1], axis[2], axis[3]);
}
public void translateX(double x){
    pos[0]+=x;
}
public void translateY(double y){
    pos[1]+=y;
}
public void translateZ(double z){
    pos[2]+=z;
}
public void translate(double x, double y, double z){
    pos[0]+=x;
    pos[1]+=y;
    pos[2]+=z;
}
public void rotateX(float x){
    Quaternion nrot = fromEuler(x,0,0);
    Quaternion.mul(nrot, rotation, rotation);
}
public void rotateY(float y){
    Quaternion nrot = fromEuler(0,y,0);
    Quaternion.mul(nrot, rotation, rotation);
}
public void rotateZ(float z){
    Quaternion nrot = fromEuler(0,0,z);
    Quaternion.mul(nrot, rotation, rotation);
}
public void rotate(int x, int y, int z){
    Quaternion nrot = fromEuler(x,y,z);
    Quaternion.mul(nrot, rotation, rotation);
}
private Quaternion fromEuler(float x, float y, float z){

    float pitch = y * PI180 / 2.0f;
    float yaw = z * PI180 / 2.0f;
    float roll = x * PI180 / 2.0f;

    float sinp = (float)Math.sin(pitch);
    float siny = (float)Math.sin(yaw);
    float sinr = (float)Math.sin(roll);
    float cosp = (float)Math.cos(pitch);
    float cosy = (float)Math.cos(yaw);
    float cosr = (float)Math.cos(roll);

    Quaternion q = new Quaternion();
    q.x = sinr * cosp * cosy - cosr * sinp * siny;
    q.y = cosr * sinp * cosy + sinr * cosp * siny;
    q.z = cosr * cosp * siny - sinr * sinp * cosy;
    q.w = cosr * cosp * cosy + sinr * sinp * siny;

    q.normalise();

    return q;
}
private float[] getAxisAngle(){
    float scale = (float)Math.sqrt(rotation.x * rotation.x + rotation.y * rotation.y + rotation.z * rotation.z);
    return new float[]{(float)Math.acos(rotation.w)*2,rotation.x/scale, rotation.y/scale, rotation.z/scale};
}
}
```

In my code, 3D objects extends from this class and i call rotateZ(1) at each frame.

Video of the result :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JbOTvOPBJVY&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Firstly, why are you creating an Euler rotation and then converting this to a Quaternion? If you want to use quaternions then only use them. Secondly please provide a standalone complete example of how to replicate your issue